# How to sumif when the range contains comma delimited values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

[image]

FYI Tb1 is on the left and Tb2 is on the right

My problem: I want to sumif on the range that contains comma delimited values. Tb2 will be my final output.

I have tried wildcard but it only worked on string character. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like:

[image]

You can use PowerQuery for this

- Select your data > Data Tab > Get & Transform > Insert from Table/Range > Choose with headers
- In PQ select `ID` column > Transform Tab > Split column > By delimiter > Choose by comma > Advanced settings > Split to rows and no quotes > Confirm
- Keep ID column selected > Transform Tab > Group by > Group by `ID` > Choose `SUM` as operation on column `Total` (and pick a new column name if you want).
- Exit PQ and confirm to save your changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume your Criteria range "ID" put in D2:D5

Result "Total" in E2, copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,$A$2:$A$6))*$B$2:$B$6)
```